# Trouble Linking index.html to css folder in 16.04

Tags: apache2, html, css

I've built an Apache2 webserver in 16.04. Currently, my index.html is located in /var/www/html/index.html. I try to call some css using this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/basic.css" media="screen" />
```

The file basic.css is located at /var/www/css/basic.css. I figure my href is wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to place your css folder in the html folder so /var/www/html/css/...
you can do this by

```
sudo mv /var/www/css /var/www/html/css
```

OR you have to reference `href="../css/basic.css"`

But usually you should prefer the first way.

Anyway in both cases make sure you have the rights set correctly e.g. by

```
sudo chown -R <username>:www-data /var/www/html/css
```

or in the second case

```
sudo chown -R <username>:www-data /var/www/css
```

Comment: Is it bad design to keep my CSS folder inside the HTML folder? If not should I also keep my JS and IMG files in the HTML folder?

Comment: In contrary I would say it is bad design to keep the css folder outside because usually /var/www/html is the root folder used by Apache2.

I usually do everything in subfolders of /var/www/html for example in folders called "css" "php" "js" "img" "html" since it is not forbidden to have a subfolder which is called html as well ;) Only be carefull than where you are in your path when doing actions on the files

Comment: Ok thanks! Should I keep my index.html in the first HTML file, not the second?

Comment: You have to if you do not want to change the config of apache2 to search it in another folder